# Marshal array of strings

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

Given a VB6 struct & a C++ function declaration like below:

```
Type MYTYPE
    MyField(MAX) AS String * MAX_LENGTH
End Type

Declare Function CFunction Lib "MyCLib.dll" (ByRef data As MYTYPE) As Long
```

What is the correct way to pass this struct to C++ API in C#? Let say I want to do the following in C#:

```
MYTYPE myType = new MYTYPE();
myType.MyField[0] = "Some value";
CFunction(ref myType);
```

**Update**

I used the following  definition for the struct:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MYTYPE {
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = MAX * MAX_LENGTH)]
    public string MyField;
}
```

This way, i am able to read/write string array. Of course it looks a bit ugly because i have to parse the string array myself, but it works without being involved `AllocHGlobal` & its `FreeHGlobal` counterpart which I was trying to avoid.

Comment: To marshal arrays from managed to unmanaged parts you should use `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` to allocate memory between them then fill the array with `Marshal.Copy` then pass your `IntPtr` to the allocated array call your native function and then use `Marshal.FreeHGlobal` to free allocated memory.

Comment: I once succesfully mapped data coming from a VB legacy procedure by using attributes like (copy-pasted): `[VBFixedString(21), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 21)]` or `[VBFixedArray(31)]`. Sorry if this doesn't apply to you, it just came to my mind and I thought it worth sharing.